# Register WCF proxy wrapper using Unity

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, proxy, unity-container

I am trying to consume WCF in my MVC web app. I have implemented the channel factory for instantiating the proxy client. 
I am stuck at a point. Here is the code highlight -

I created a proxy base class where i am creating the channel :

```
public abstract class ServiceProxyBase<T> : IDisposable where T : class
```

For creating teh proxy wrapper class i have inherited this base class as :

```
public class ProxyWrapper : ServiceProxyBase<IMyService>,IMyService
```

Here "IMyService" is the WCf contract.

Now, in the controllers i have added overloaded constructors as :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IMyService businessService;

    public AccountController(IMyService _businessService)
    {
       this.businessService = _businessService;
    }
}
```

For injecting dependency I have included unity.mvc4 package.

It works fine when I am using the following code :

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService, ProxyWrapper>();
```

This works as long as the ProxyWrapper is inheriting the IMyService interface directly. If i remove the inheritance like

```
public class ProxyWrapper : ServiceProxyBase<IMyService>
```

it gives an error while registering type.
I would like to have a way without inherting the contract in the proxy wrapper. I have spent almost a day trying to fix this. But am able to figure out a solution.

Please give your valuable suggestions on this.

Comment: So you want to register the `ProxyWrapper` as `IMyService` but without letting the `ProxyWrapper` implement `IMyService`? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Yes I want to implement it the way to mentioned. I am not trying to solve any problems. Just trying to implement it in a more cleaner way so that i dont have to implement all the methods of the contract in the wrapper. Only the ones i need should be included.

Comment: @Steven - Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your application is using a WCF service but the functionality your application needs is limited compared to the functionality that the service offers (it contains more methods than you need). According to the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), "no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use" and the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) states that clients own the abstraction.

In other words, you should define your own interface that the application should use and define an implementation that wraps (i.e. [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)) the generated WCF proxy class.

For instance:

```cs
public interface IMyApplicationService
{
    object GetStuff();
    void PutStuff(object instance);
}

public class MyServiceApplicationProxy : IMyApplicationService
{
    private readonly ProxyWrapper wcfProxy;

    public MyServiceApplicationProxy(ProxyWrapper wcfProxy) {
        this.wcfProxy = wcfProxy;
    }

    public object GetStuff() {
        return this.wcfProxy.GetStuff();
    }

    public void PutStuff(object instance) {
        this.wcfProxy.PutStuff(instance);
    }
}
```

To make application development easier, makes your code easier to read, maintain and test.

You might even want to change the methods of your interface to better suit your application needs. Remember: the client defines the interface! So that might mean that you need to do more mapping inside the `MyServiceApplicationProxy` class to map adapt your core domain to the contract of the external web service. Don't let the external WCF service's contract leak into your core domain.